# Nav Bar Problems with Position Fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

The main objective for me is to make a nav-bar that has a position fixed. I'm not able to introduce it since once I put the element in my `.nav{}` all the children element squeeze to the top left-hand corner. Right now this is what I have:

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`;
      }
    });
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: #5D4954;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 80%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
/* Commented so as to reproduce the problem visually
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #5D4954;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5 ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}*/

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
```

```html
<html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h4>The Nav</h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>
        <a href="#start">Get Started</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#information">Information</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#survey">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your link to code is missing/empty

Comment: https://codepen.io/Ganz0R/pen/BaoVPMx --> Here is the link.

Comment: So, do you want to make navbar cover the whole width, then do `width:100%`. Is it?

Comment: That just might be it. I've tried it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `width: 100%;` to your `nav{}` rules